# How to add a texture inside a specific area in a canvas in javascript?

Tags: textures, javascript

How could I draw a texture between the bottom of the canvas and below the green line, in javascript?
I dynamically add coordinates in a canvas, then draw lines between these points.

EDIT : Solution: so I had to do it like this :

```
let path = 'M'+points[i-1].x+' '+points[i-1].y;
path += 'L'+points[i].x+' '+points[i].y;
//etc... with "Z" for closing the path, then :
let p = new Path2D(path);
ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createPattern(imgTexture, "repeat");
ctx.fill(p);
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for [How to fill an area with a bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30503322/js-canvas-how-to-fill-area-with-bitmap)?

Comment: @DMGregory if I use drawImage, I have to repeat the whole image, and I'm not sure how to make a nice transition between 2 images side by side. Also, with the curve lines, there are many segments to simulate the curve. I saw a method using triangles but it is with software like libGdx I think.

Comment: You should probably consider looking at the answers at the link above that don't use DrawImage then.  You can use an image patterned fill as part of the regular Canvas API, no special tricks or other software required.

Comment: @DMGregory great thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: so I had to do it like this :

```
let path = 'M'+points[i-1].x+' '+points[i-1].y;
path += 'L'+points[i].x+' '+points[i].y;
//etc... with "Z" for closing the path, then :
let p = new Path2D(path);
ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createPattern(imgTexture, "repeat");
ctx.fill(p);
```